# wiremock request matching from key=value pair

Tags: wiremock

I am using json mapping to match the request. The request coming as content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded which means as a Key=value pair and the value contains xml data. For example:

```
REQUEST=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <n:request xmlns:n="schema uri" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="schema location">
        <header userId="userId" password="password" requesterId="123" version="100" language="de">
            <product>xxx</product>
        </header>
        <subject>
            <party externalIdentifier="1">
                <address externalIdentifier="11">
                    <person>
                        <firstName>rinku</firstName>
                        <lastName>chy</lastName>
                        <birthDate>1973-12-10</birthDate>
                    </person>
                    <street>street</street>
                    <number>12</number>
                    <countryCode>de</countryCode>
                    <zipCode>123</zipCode>
                    <city>city</city>
                </address>
            </party>
        </subject>
    </n:request>
```

The purpose is to find the product name and the person's name. I have tried both xpath as well as query parameters expression to match the request as stated in http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/. But couldn't manage to get a solution yet.For example

```
{
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "urlPattern": "/mock.*",
            "queryParameters": {
                "product": {
                    "matches": "xxx"
                }
            }, 
// tried both seperately
            "bodyPatterns": [
                {
                    "matchesXPath": "//*[local-name()='request']/*[local-name()='header']/*[local-name()='product'][text()='xxx']"
                }
            ]
        },
        "response": {
            "status": 200,
            "bodyFileName": "response.xml",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
                "Content-Location": "response.xml"
            }
        }
    }
```

Always getting the same error "[WireMock] (qtp2017957857-34) Warning: failed to parse the XML document. Reason: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Can anyone have a clue how to match such a request?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. There is an option to intercept and modify requests. Visit -> http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/ in the section "Intercepting and modifying requests".

```
public class RequestFilter extends StubRequestFilter {

@Override
public RequestFilterAction filter(Request request) {

    // removed "REQUEST=" from request body
    Request modifyRequest = RequestWrapper.create()
            .transformBody(requestBody -> Body.fromOneOf(null, requestBody.asString().substring(8)), null, null))
            .wrap(request);

    return RequestFilterAction.continueWith(modifyRequest);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "my-request-filter";
}}
```